# Video mute/unmute button javaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, audio, html5-video, mute

JavaScript beginner here!

I am trying to make a video player in javaScript for a school project but I am having trouble with my mute button.

I want the button to mute the video when clicked and unmute if the button is pressed again. So far I have only been able to mute the video and keep it muted.

Here is my current mute button.

```
var button = document.getElementById('mute');
    button.onclick = function (){
        video.muted = true;
    };
```

I tried an if else statement but it was unsuccessful

```
var button = document.getElementById('mute');
    button.onclick = function (){

    if (video.muted = false) {    
           video.muted = true;
    }

    else {
        video.muted = false;
    }

    };
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happened when you tried the if else statement? Did you get any console errors?

Comment: No errors, the button just ceases to function.

Answer (score 11):

```
if (video.muted = false) {    
       video.muted = true;
}
```

This should be

```
if (video.muted === false) {    
       video.muted = true;
}
```

Or else the else statement will never run, since you are setting video.muted to false every time in the if statement itself.

Comment: not worked, as browser chrome is showing error uncaughtexception.... user has to interact with DOM first.

Answer (score 2):

### Enter Bitwise XOR (^)

```
video.muted ^= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because instead of you are actually checking whether muted attribute is false or true, you are assigning false to the muted attribute.

So you should write as follow:

```
if (video.muted === false) {    
    video.muted = true;
}
else {
    // your code
};
```