# How to Unmute and Restart Video?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Can not figure out how to restart and unmute video altogether:

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var play = document.getElementById('play');

video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    video.muted = true;
    video.play();
});

play.addEventListener('click', function() {
    player.classList.add('is-open');
    video.muted = false;
    video.load();
    video.play();
});
```

Comment: if(video.muted) video.muted = false; if(!video.muted) video.muted = true;

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw Not working

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060291/video-mute-unmute-button-javascript

Comment: Also, are you not using the built in controls ? For video element?

Comment: @K3N Yes, now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @walterdesign no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that when you process the `click` event, the `canplay` event is re-triggered, and since it comes afterwards it will reapply muted state.

You can use some flag or unsubscribe the `canplay` event the second time you need to play the video - or set `autoplay` and `muted` in the video element itself without using the `canplay` event.

```
var first = true;

video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    if (first) {
      video.muted = true;
      video.play();
      first = false;
    }
});
```